# Eval() and base class properties

Tags: asp.net, inheritance, eval

I have class `Foo` which defines property `Id`. Class `Bar` inherits from `Foo` (`class Bar : Foo`).

If I assign a `List<Bar>` to `Repeater.DataSource` then use `Eval("Id")` in the `ItemTemplate`, the following exception is thrown:

> DataBinding: 'Bar' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'.

Any way around this?  `Id` is a valid property of Bar, it's just defined on Foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me.  Maybe you have a visibility problem?  What is the access modifier on the **Id** property?

Here is my source:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
      bars.Add(new Bar());
      bars.Add(new Bar());
      bars.Add(new Bar());

      Repeater1.DataSource = bars;
      Repeater1.DataBind();
   }
}

public class Foo
{
   public Foo()
   {
      this.FooProp = "FooPropValue";
   }

   public string FooProp { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
   public Bar()
   {
      this.BarProp = "BarPropValue!";
   }

   public string BarProp { get; set; }
}
```

And in the ASPX I have:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("FooProp")%></ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Great, I feel like an idiot.  In my defense it was the end of the week. :)